# Java program doesn't print some code to console

Tags: java, console-application

I'm trying to compare the execution times of brute force search vs binary search on a whitelist.

## Problem

When I run `java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt`, elapsedTime and the "test" string are not output to console but they are output to console for `java BruteForceSearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt`.

**Note**: I'm using external library from [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/) to do the I/O operation.

### Brute force

```
public class BruteForceSearch {

    public static int rank (int key, int[] a) {
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            if(a[i] == key)
                return i;

    return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("test");

        // read the integers from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();

        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        // read integer key from standard input; print if not in whitelist
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
                StdOut.println(key);
        }

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

### Binary search

```
public class BinarySearch {

    public static int rank(int key, int[] a) {
        int lo = 0;
        int hi = a.length - 1;
        while (lo <= hi) {
            // Key is in a[lo..hi] or not present.
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;

            if (key < a[mid]) hi = mid - 1;
            else if (key > a[mid]) lo = mid + 1;
            else return mid;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("test");

        // read the integers from a file
        In in = new In(args[0]);
        int[] whitelist = in.readAllInts();

        // sort the array
        Arrays.sort(whitelist);

        // read integer key from standard input; print if not in whitelist
        while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
            int key = StdIn.readInt();
            if (rank(key, whitelist) == -1)
            StdOut.println(key);
        }

        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);
    }
}
```

### tinyW.txt

```
84
48
68
10
18
98
12
23
54
57
48
33
16
77
11
29
```

### tinyT.txt

```
23
50
10
99
18
23
98
84
11
10
48
77
13
54
98
77
77
68
```

### Output for `java BruteForceSearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt`

```
test
50
99
13
elapsed time: 33
```

### Output for `java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt`

```
50
99
13
```

Comment: what debugging have you done? sound like an infinite loop without looking @ the code

Comment: Looking at your definition of BinarySearch, it'd be pretty impossible for it not to output "test" unless it's crashing, which doesn't seem to be happening based on your output...are you sure you're running the code exactly as you've posted (and not some previously compiled version of it)?

Comment: Do you have the In class so I can try this out?

Comment: @Steve - I have re-checked the code several times. It's not an infinite loop because there is output and I've posted it.

Comment: @Chris - I'm sure I'm running the code posted here. I've also recompiled it several times, still getting the same output.

Comment: @Alvin Bunk - Sure, it can be found here along with other classes I'm using. http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Comment: Could you please try removing all the code **but leaving `System.out.println("test")` there**, then compile and run again? I know it might seem ridiculous, but at least worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

I copied all those files to a single directory, namely the files:
BinarySearch.java, In.java, StdIn.java, StdOut.java, tinyT.txt, tinyW.txt

Then ran the following:

```
javac BinarySearch.java
```

then:

```
D:\temp\BinarySearch>java BinarySearch tinyW.txt < tinyT.txt
test
50
99
13
elapsed time: 249
```

Notice it printed the output...

Can you try my same steps?